# Is it possible to use the 1 day premium passport service for someone visiting the UK for a day?

Tags: uk, passports, uk-citizens, passport-renewals, biometric-passports

My sister is planning to come to the UK just for one day in order to renew her passport. Will she be able to use [the 1 day Premium service](https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently)?

Comment: Your sister does know that she can renew her UK passport while abroad?

Comment: @DJClayworth yes but it's kind of a big hassle in the corrupted country she resides in.

Comment: As UK citizens have only one piece of ID that is suitable to cross borders it is not always possible for UK citizens to renew while doing their normal work life. Friends brother lives in Germany and works in Switzerland, that is a weekly commute at least, and often travels for work. No way to renew by sending in passport. One day service in the UK did work.

Comment: Does the person applying for the renewed passport have to be the one who collects the new passport? Can another person go to collect?

Comment: @user128278 you get the passport at the appointment. So obviously it’s has to be the applicant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes she can, provided she applies for it once she is in the UK. She can go one step ahead and [Use the Online Premium (1 day) service](https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently/online-premium-1-day-service).  That is a new trial service and basic conditions are:

> - You’ll apply online with a digital photo and book an appointment to collect your new passport from a passport office.
> - You need to be 16 or older to use the service.
> - You can’t use the Online Premium service to get your first UK passport or to replace a lost, stolen or damaged passport.

Here is a wizard that she can use to check if she qualifies for this trial service: https://www.passport.service.gov.uk/urgent/online-premium

> **Apply with Online Premium**
>
> To try Online Premium you’ll need to:
>
> 1 Answer some questions to check you can use this service
>
> 2 Choose an appointment to collect your new passport
>
> 3 Get your digital photo – we’ll show you how
>
> 4 Apply online and pay with a debit or credit card
>
> 5 Collect your new passport – it usually takes 30 minutes